# Setting url after log out in asp net visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, logout

I have an admin folder and admin user. If I go into a page in the admin folder with premissions only to admin when I click logout - it sends me to a page I dont want.
How can i set this url?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
 LogoutAction="Redirect"
 LogoutPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
```

or

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="[Spefify Page Here]" />
</authentication>
```